# Get records created after a particular time of day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Say I have an `Event` model with a `date_time` field representing the date time the event is held, and I want to see all Events that are held, say, 'after 10pm', or 'before 7am' across multiple dates. How could I do this?

---

My first thought was something like this:

`scope :after_time ->(time){ where("events.date_time::time between ?::time and '23:59'::time", time) }`

But this doesn't work because dates are stored in UTC and converted to the app's timezone by ActiveRecord.

So let's say I'm searching for Events after 5pm, from my local Adelaide time. The eventual query is this:

`WHERE (events.date_time::time between '2016-10-09 06:30:00.000000'::time and '23:59'::time)`

That is, because my timezone is +10:30 (Adelaide time), it's now trying to calculate between 6:30am and midnight, where it really needs to be finding ones created between 6:30am and 1:30pm utc.

Now, for this example in particular I could probably hack something together to work out what the 'midnight' time needs to be given the time zone difference. But the `between <given time> and <midnight in Adelaide>` calculation isn't going to work if that period spans midnight utc. So that solution is bust.

---

UPDATE:

I *think* I've managed to get the result I want by trial and error, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what's going on.

`scope :after_time,  ->(time) {
    time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    where_clause = <<-SQL
      (events.date_time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'ACDT')::time
      between ? and '23:59:59'
    SQL
    joins(:performances).where(where_clause, time)
  }`

It's basically turning everything into the one time zone so the query for each row ends up looking something like `WHERE '20:30:00' between '17:00:00' and '23:59:59'`, so I'm not having to worry about times spanning over midnight.

Even still, I feel like there's probably a proper way to do this, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you,

```
s = DateTime.now.change(hour: 6, min: 30).utc
e = Date.today.end_of_day.utc
Event.where("date_time::time between ?::time and ?::time", s, e)
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question. I need to get events across multiple dates, but after/before certain times on those dates. For for example, the might be 3 events in the database, one on the January 1st at 5pm, one on January 2nd at 6pm, and one on January 3rd at 7pm. I want to be able to find all the Events with a time later (or equal to) 6pm. That is, I need a query that will find the second and third events, but not the first.

Comment: @Obversity I have updated my answer. I think it will work for you. Please test this on your data.

Comment: Here's the where clause that generates: `WHERE (events.date_time::time between '2016-10-08 20:00:00.000000'::time and '2016-10-09 13:29:59.999999'::time)`. As you can probably guess, this isn't going to find any results, because it's going to be looking for records between '20:00:00' and '13:29:59', which isn't a valid period of time. (I'd actually tried this previously, I probably should have mentioned that in the question. Sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

this may help you and then you need not to convert every date of DB, instead you can convert the parameterized timestamp into UTC time:

```
scope :after, ->(start_time) { where('created_at::time > :time', time: start_time.utc.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) }
```

Now,
for e.g. I do have 3 events for following timestamps(all in UTC):

1. 2013-04-11 11:43:43
2. 2013-04-11 15:10:40
3. 2013-04-12 07:39:26

and then you can call:

```
start_time = Time.zone.parse('2016-01-01 20:00:00')
# => Fri, 01 Jan 2016 20:00:00 ACDT +10:30
Event.after(start_time) # this will return 2 events(1, 2)
```

query will be:

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (created_at::time > '09:30:00')
```

> Note: This will raise an error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous` if you will use this query with any another model that will have `created_at` column